# Photoshop Javascript - can't get the script to edit a newly created text layer

Tags: javascript, select, photoshop, layer

This is probably a really basic issue, but I can't get a script to resize a text layer that was made earlier in the script. I make a new text layer at the beginning of the script and it is supposed to be resized depending on the size of the document, but instead the script tries to resize the locked Background layer, causing an error because the Transform command is not available. I don't have this problem when I use a separate script to create the text layer, just when the new layer is created within the same script. I would really like to only have to run one script in an action instead of two.

Here is the pertinent part of the script (I have commented out some previous efforts to select the new text layer):

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var layer = doc.activeLayer;

var newTextLayer = doc.artLayers.add();
newTextLayer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
newTextLayer.name = "textLayer";
var text = newTextLayer.textItem;
text.contents = "TEST TEXT";
text.color = white;

app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS; 

//create the color for the tab extension
var black = new SolidColor();  
black.rgb.hexValue = "111111";
app.backgroundColor = black;


//******************FOR EXTENDING CANVAS AND POSITIONING/RESIZING THE TEXT LAYER**************************

var orgWidth = doc.width;
var orgHeight = doc.height;

//var topLayer = app.activeDocument.layers.index(0);
//var txtLayer = app.activeDocument.TextItem.getByName("textLayer");

if(orgWidth>orgHeight) //if document is landscape, resize text to fill a smaller portion of the tab
{
//doc.activeLayer = doc.layers["textLayer"];
//doc.layers.getByName("textLayer");
layer.resize(((orgWidth-orgWidth*.2)/(layer.bounds[2]-    layer.bounds[0]))*100,(orgWidth*.03/(layer.bounds[3]-    layer.bounds[1]))*100,AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);     


doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, (orgHeight + orgWidth*.04), AnchorPosition.TOPCENTER);

layer.translate(undefined, new UnitValue(0-layer.bounds[1].as('px'),'px'));  
layer.translate(undefined, orgHeight); 
layer.translate(undefined, (orgWidth*.02-((layer.bounds[3]-layer.bounds[1])/2.3)));     
}
else //otherwise, resize text to fill a larger portion of the tab
{
//doc.activeLayer = doc.layers["textLayer"];
//doc.layers.getByName("textLayer");
layer.resize(((orgWidth-orgWidth*.05)/(layer.bounds[2]-    layer.bounds[0]))*100,(orgWidth*.03/(layer.bounds[3]-    layer.bounds[1]))*100,AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT); 


    doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, (orgHeight + orgWidth*.04), AnchorPosition.TOPCENTER);

    layer.translate(undefined, new UnitValue(0-layer.bounds[1].as('px'),'px'));  
layer.translate(undefined, orgHeight); 
layer.translate(undefined, (orgWidth*.02-((layer.bounds[3]-layer.bounds[1])/2.3))); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think  the variable layer is not defined anywhere ? maybe you mean newTextLayer instead ? as in newTextLayer.resize newTextLayer.translate

Comment: @bfmags Oh, sorry, there are two lines above the selection that I put up that should have been included: var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var layer = doc.activeLayer;

Comment: layer = doc.activeLayer; so, you're applying the transformations to the active layer in the document when you run the script, and not the text layer. You just need to change layer to newTextLayer after (...)*FOR EXTENDING CANVAS(...)

Comment: @bfmags Great! This works perfectly. Thank you so much!